# How to limit a ManyToMany with an extra where clause in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I'm retrieving data from a legacy database, thus have no control at all over the schema.

I frequently need to check for a static value in a separate column to remove false matches.

```
create table mySource (
id int,
...
)

create table aRelation (
srcId int,
myFK int,
relationLimit varchar
)

create table aTarget (
id int,
...
myFK int,
aLimit varchar,
...
)
```

"relationLimit" and/or "aLimit" above must match a static value.

I can only find the standard annotations:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "aRelation",
    joinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "srcId") },
       @inverseJoinColumns = {
           @JoinColumn(name = "myFK", referencedColumnName = "myFK")
    })
private List<ATarget> targets;
```

But I can't find any way to annotate the requirement(s)

```
aLimit = "Something"
relationLimit="SomethingElse"
```

If this is obvious in the documentation please tell me how and where to read it.

Comment: map your classes correctly, so you have an intermediate class and 2 1-N relations. Then you can do it in a portable JPA way. M-N join tables have no "extra column"

Comment: why not using a JPQL query with the conditions?

Comment: @NeilStockton I could, but it feels bad to introduce a class for something that has no behaviour and no data in my application. The extra fields above are used by the other application using the same database, I'm trying to show a subset of it.

Comment: @ujulu I could use JPQL, in fact I probably will describe this in NativeSQL but I need to get JPA/Hibernate to create the correct table structure for the unit-tests and I would like to have the relation descriptions collected where they would be expected to be found.

Comment: `it feels bad to introduce a class for something that has no behaviour and no data in my application`: but what @NeilStockton has suggessted is the normal way if these attributes apply to the relationship. If your current mapping is not working as expected it might be because of the `@` symbol infront of the attribute `inverseJoinColumns`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Hibernate you can try `@Filter` annotation on entity.

```
@Filter(name="betweenLength", condition="aLimit = 'Something' and relationLimit='SomethingElse'")
```

More on this topic you can find [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)